# Proving that closed (and open) balls are convex

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed linear space, $x\in X$ and $r>0$. Define the open and closed ball centered at $x$ as 
$$
B(x, r) = \{y \in X : \Vert x − y\Vert < r\}
$$ 
$$
\overline{B}(x, r) = \{y \in X : \Vert x − y\Vert \leq r\}.
$$
Then $B(x, r)$ and $\overline{B}(x, r)$ are convex.

I tried to prove this, but either my calculation is incorrect, or I am on the wrong path:

I aim to show for the closed ball $\overline{B}(x,r)$ (for open ball I assume the proof is similar). Suppose $y,z \in \overline{B}(x, r)$. Then $\Vert x − y\Vert \leq r$ and $\Vert x − z\Vert \leq r$. We must show that $t \in [0,1]$ implies $ty + (1-t)z \in \overline{B}(x,r)$. But $t \in [0,1]$ implies
$$
\Vert ty + (1-t)z - x\Vert = \Vert t(y-z) + z - x\Vert
\leq |t| \Vert y-z\Vert + \Vert z-x\Vert
\leq |t|(\Vert y-x\Vert + \Vert x-z\Vert) + \Vert z-x\Vert
< |t|(2r) + r = r(2|t| + 1),
$$
which is not necessarily $\leq r$. We probably wanted to end up with $< |t|r$ or $\leq |t|r$ as our final inequality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$
ty+(1-t)z-x=t(y-x)+(1-t)(z-x)
$$

Comment: That trick is a bit too sneaky for my liking, haha. Thanks

Comment: In mathmatics there are much more neat tricks. This one is standard.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this trick before. Just didn't recognize it in this situation...

Comment: Sorry, but how do you conclude? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Right, but have you used that $B_1(0)$ is convex?

Comment: I proved this $\phantom{}$

Comment: by the way is there some source to find some neat and standart tricks?

Comment: @Anil - Not sure. I think in general you learn each individual "trick" when you come across them. It's a bit like the saying, "I'll cross that bridge when I get there". But there may be some sort of list of these types of algebra tricks, I'm not sure. Maybe ask that as a new question.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose $x, y$ are in a unit closed ball. Consider
 $$||z||=||(1-a)x+ay||\leq (1-a)||x||+a||y||\leq 1-a+a=1.$$
So $||z||\leq 1$, so $z$ is in unit close ball.

Comment: Please use MathJax/LaTeX markup to improve readability! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $ B(a,r)=\{y \in X: \|y-a\| < r \}$ be an open ball in a Banach space $X$. Let $x,y \in B(x,r)$ then  $\| x-a\| < r $ and $\| y-a\| < r $. $$\|x\|-\|a\| <\| x-a\| < r ~~ and~~ \|y\|-\|a\| <\| y-a\| < r$$ which implies \begin{equation} \|x\| < r + \|a\|,~ \|y\| < r + \|a\|~~~~~~    (1) \end{equation}
for any $t \in [0,1]$; $x,y \in X$ using $(1)$ we have
$$
\|tx+(1-t)y\| \leq t\|x\|+(1-t)\|y
 < t(r+\|a\|)+(1-t)(r+\|a\|)=r+\|a\|\\
$$ Since $a$ is the centre (Origin) of the ball $\|a\|=0$. Hence, the result $\square$

Comment: If $a$ is centre of the ball, then isn't $\|a-a\|=0$ instead?