# Metric balls with finite perimeter

Tags: metric-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

I have a couple of questions of the same nature related to the perimeters of metric balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$. By perimeter, I mean the notion of perimeter reffered by the [Caccioppoli definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caccioppoli_set), i.e. the perimeter of $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ in an open set $\Omega$  is the total variation of its characteristic function on that open set.

1. Must the metric ball $B_d(x, \delta) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ have finite perimeter for any distance function $d$?
2. Same question, but this time $d$ being a distance induced by a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: This isn't my area, but I just wanted to say, you can choose any non-empty $\Omega \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ you wish, and there exists a metric whose open ball (or closed ball) is equal to this $\Omega$. All you do is define$$d(x, y) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x = y \\ 1 & \text{otherwise if }x, y \in \Omega \\ 2 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$and any (open or closed) ball of radius $1.5$ centred in $\Omega$ is equal to $\Omega$. I would imagine that this answers your first question in the negative, but I can't be sure.

Comment: That's a good point! I had the intuition that the first question should be false. After your comments, I was looking for a similar result for a norm $\| \cdot \|$. Any closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137738/proving-that-closed-and-open-balls-are-convex). Conversely, any bounded, open, convex, and the centre symmetry set having centre at 0 will induce a norm (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137738/proving-that-closed-and-open-balls-are-convex). This might help answer the second point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a norm $|\cdot| : \mathbb{R}^{d} \to [0,\infty)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.  Recall that $\|\cdot\|$ is equivalent to the Euclidean norm $\|\cdot\|$, that is, there is a $C > 1$ such that
\begin{equation*}
C^{-1} \|v\| \leq |v| \leq C\|v\| \quad \text{if} \, \, v \in \mathbb{R}^{d}.
\end{equation*}
Hence $v \mapsto |v|$ is Lipschitz as $||w| - |v|| \leq |w - v| \leq C\|w - v\|$.  By the co-area formula,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\{y \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \, \mid \, |y| \leq 1\}} \|D|\cdot|(x)\| \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} P(\{y \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \, \mid \, |y| = r\}) \, dr
\end{equation*}
Hence there is an $r \in (0,1)$ such that $P(\{y \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \, \mid \, |y| = r\}) < \infty$.  At the same time, for any $s > 0$, we have
\begin{equation*}
P(\{y \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \, \mid \, |y| = r\}) = P(r s^{-1} \{y \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \, \mid \, |y| = s\}) = (r s^{-1})^{d-1} P(\{y \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \, \mid \, |y| = 1\}).
\end{equation*}
Thus, the $|\cdot|$-ball centered at the origin has finite perimeter, no matter the radius.  Perimeter is translation-invariant, though, so any ball has finite perimeter, no matter the center or the radius.

Another proof I can think of uses the fact that if $C_{1}, C_{2}$ are convex sets and $C_{1} \subseteq C_{2}$, then $P(C_{1}) \leq P(C_{2})$: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262568/a-convex-subset-of-a-set-has-smaller-boundary-than-the-set), for instance.  I suspect there are other easier proofs.

**Edit:**  It's worth remarking that the argument above shows any convex set $C$ has locally finite perimeter.

First, note that if $C$ has empty interior, then it is contained in an affine hyperplane.  In this case, $C$ has Lebesgue measure zero so it trivially has finite perimeter.  We assume henceforth that $C$ has nonempty interior.

Note that if $C$ is convex, then $\text{int}(C)$ is also convex.  Let us show, then, that open convex sets have locally finite perimeter.
One concludes by arguing that $C \setminus \text{int}(C)$ has zero Lebesgue measure.

Fix $x_{0} \in C$ and $R > 0$ arbitrary.  Define the Minkowski gauge $\psi_{R}$ by
\begin{equation*}
\psi_{R}(y) = \inf \left\{ \alpha \, \mid \, \alpha^{-1} y \in (C - x_{0}) \cap B(0,R) \right\}.
\end{equation*}
It is well-known (see, for example, Brezis's functional analysis textbook) that $\psi_{R}$ is a Finsler norm: it is convex and one-homogeneous.  (It satisfies all the hypotheses of a norm, except for symmetry.)  In particular, as in the case of a genuine norm, $\psi_{R}$ is Lipschitz.

Arguing as above, we see that $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \, \mid \, \psi_{R}(y) = s\}$ has finite perimeter for each $s \in (0,\infty)$.  Translating (and setting $s = 1$), this implies that $C \cap B(x_{0},R)$ has finite perimeter.  Given that this is true for all $R > 0$, we conclude $C$ has finite perimeter.

(Other proofs might be shorter, but recently I find working with gauges makes proving things easier.)

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful ! I have also come across an argument proving that a convex set must have locally finite perimeter (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355693/every-convex-set-is-of-locally-finite-perimeter). Since in $\mathbb{R}^n$, closed balls induced by a norm are convex and compact, I guess we can deduce that they are also of finite perimeter.

Comment: That claim --- convex sets have locally finite perimeter --- is related to your question about norms.  I added an edit explaining why.